# Writing to coredata, even when done on background thread , blocks the UI considerably

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

Iam trying out a chat based app. I have setup a singleton coredata manager as follows

```
#import "CGSharedCoreData.h"
CGSharedCoreData *_cd;


@implementation CGSharedCoreData

@synthesize managedObjectModel = managedObjectModel_;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext_;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator_;


+ (CGSharedCoreData *)sharedCoreData{
    static CGSharedCoreData *_cd = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceCoreDataShared;
    dispatch_once(&onceCoreDataShared, ^{
        _cd = [[CGSharedCoreData alloc] init];
    });
    return _cd;
}


+ (void)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)c{

    @try {


        if (c.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.count == 0)
        {
            // This is the case where the persistent store is cleared during a logout.
            CGLog(@"saveContext: PersistentStoreCoordinator is deallocated.");
            return;
        }


        // Register context with the notification center
        NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        CGSharedCoreData *sharedCoreData = [CGSharedCoreData sharedCoreData];

        [nc addObserver:sharedCoreData
               selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                 object:c];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (c != nil) {
            CGLog(@"thread  &&*&(*(* %d",[NSThread isMainThread]);
            if ([c hasChanges] && ![c save:&error]) {
                CGLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }

        [nc removeObserver:sharedCoreData name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                    object:c];

    }

    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        CGLog(@"***** Unresolved CoreData exception %@", [exception description]);
    }

}


+ (dispatch_queue_t) backgroundSaveQueue
{
    static dispatch_queue_t coredata_background_save_queue;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        coredata_background_save_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.shashank.coredata.backgroundsaves", NULL);
    });

    return coredata_background_save_queue;
}


+ (void)performInTheBackground:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext *blockContext))bgBlock {

    dispatch_async([CGSharedCoreData backgroundSaveQueue],
    ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [newContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:CG_CORE_DATA.persistentStoreCoordinator]; // Create a managed object context
        [newContext setStalenessInterval:0.0];
        [newContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];

        bgBlock(newContext);

    });
}

- (void)saveContext {
    [CGSharedCoreData saveContext:managedObjectContext_];
}

- (void)clearStore {

    NSError *error = nil;

    if  (self.persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        if ([persistentStoreCoordinator_ persistentStores] == nil) {
            CGLog(@"No persistent stores to clear!");
        }
        else {
            CGLog(@"Cleaning persistent stores!");

            managedObjectContext_ = nil;


            NSPersistentStore *store = [[persistentStoreCoordinator_ persistentStores] lastObject];

            if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ removePersistentStore:store error:&error]) {
                CGLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }

            // Delete file
            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:store.URL.path]) {
                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:store.URL.path error:&error]) {
                    CGLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    abort();
                }
            }

            // Delete the reference to non-existing store
            persistentStoreCoordinator_ = nil;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
     NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"Must be instantiated on main thread.");

    if (managedObjectContext_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext_;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        managedObjectContext_ = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext_ setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        [managedObjectContext_ setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
    }

    return managedObjectContext_;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{

    if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel_;
    }

    managedObjectModel_ = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    return managedObjectModel_;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    CGLog(@"Creating a persistent store!");

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationLibraryDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"CGChatData.sqlite"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {



        CGLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        //        abort();
        CGLog(@"Delete STORE: %d",[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]);
        persistentStoreCoordinator_ = nil;
        persistentStoreCoordinator_ = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Handling Multiple Contexts

/**
 Merges the changes from the insert contexts to the main context on the main thread.
 */

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    if(![[CGLoginEngine sharedLoginEngine] isLoggedIn])
        return;

    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                               withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    //CAUTION: Without the for clause below the NSFetchedResultsController may not capture all the changed objects.
    //For more info see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923826/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-predicate-ignores-changes-merged-from-different
    //and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590190/appending-data-to-nsfetchedresultscontroller-during-find-or-create-loop


    for (NSManagedObject *object in [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey])
    {
        [[managedObjectContext_ objectWithID:[object objectID]] willAccessValueForKey:nil];
    }


    [managedObjectContext_ mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

}
```

now , whenever i need to send a message , I am writing it to core data and updating the tableview with a fetched results controller. The writing part looks like this :

```
[CGSharedCoreData performInTheBackground:^(NSManagedObjectContext *blockContext)
         {
             CGLog(@"thread ******* is main %d",[NSThread isMainThread]);
            [[CGChatsModelController sharedChatModel] addChatWithtext:[chatMessage objectForKey:@"Message"]
                                                                              username:[chatMessage objectForKey:@"Receiver"]
                                                                             firstName:[chatMessage objectForKey:@"ReceiverFirstName"]
                                                                              lastName:[chatMessage objectForKey:@"ReceiverLastName"]
                                                                               imageId:[chatMessage objectForKey:@"ReceiverImageID"]
                                                                           createdByMe:YES
                                                                                  time:time
                                                                               context:blockContext];
              [CGSharedCoreData saveContext:blockContext];
```

But , When I send multiple messages in a very short span , it entirely blocks my UI, even when the core-data saving and all other related operations are being done on a background queue.
Is there any particular reason for why ,this is happening ?

I am attaching a few other blocks of my code for reference here :

```
- (CGChat *) addChatWithtext:(NSString *)text username:(NSString *)username firstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName imageId:(NSString *)imageId createdByMe:(BOOL)yesOrNo time:(NSDate *)date context:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = context;
    CGChat *chat = (CGChat *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CGChat" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
    chat.text = text;
    chat.createdByMe = [NSNumber numberWithBool:yesOrNo];


     chat.status = @"sent";


    [self addChat:chat toUserWithUserName:username firstName:firstName lastName:lastName imageID:imageId time:date WithContext:backgroundContext];

    return chat;

}

- (CGChat *)lookUpChatWithUserName:(NSString *)username text:(NSString *)text timeStamp:(NSString *)timeStamp createdByMe:(BOOL) yesOrNo context:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context

{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CGChat" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userIchatWith == %@ && text == %@ && timeStamp == %@ && createdByMe ==%@", [self lookUpForUserWithUsername:username inContext:context],text,timeStamp,[NSNumber numberWithBool:yesOrNo]];

    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *resultArray = nil;
    NSError *error;

    resultArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    CGChat *chat = nil;
    if ([resultArray count] > 0) {
        chat  = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return chat;

}


- (void) addChat:(CGChat *)chat toUserWithUserName:(NSString *)username firstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName imageID:(NSString *)imageId time:(NSDate *)date WithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context

{

    CGUser *user = [self lookUpForUserWithUsername:username inContext:context];

    if (!user)
    {
        user = (CGUser *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CGUser" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        user.userName = username ;


    }
    user.firstName = firstName;
    user.lastName = lastName;

    if (![user.imageID isEqualToString:imageId])
    {
        user.imageID = imageId;
    }


    CGChat *chats = [self getLastChatForUsername:username andContext:context];
    if(chats)
    {
        chats.isLastChat = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    chat.timeStamp = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    chat.isLastChat = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    chat.userIchatWith = user;
    user.timeOfLatestChat = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

}


- (CGChat *) getLastChatForUsername:(NSString *)username andContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{

    CGUser *user = [self lookUpForUserWithUsername:username inContext:context];

    if(user)
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isLastChat == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

        NSSet *filteredSet = [user.chats filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];

        return [[filteredSet allObjects] lastObject];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}


- (CGUser *) lookUpForUserWithUsername:(NSString *)username inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CGUser" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName == %@", username];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *resultArray = nil;
    NSError *error;

    resultArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    CGUser *user = nil;
    if ([resultArray count] > 0) {
        user  = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. Core Data does not throw `NSException`, do not wrap your Core Data calls in `try/catch`.  That will just create noise if something *else* does throw an exception.  `try/catch` is **VERY** rarely used in Objective-C programming.
2. You are listening for and merging changes from `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` calls when you are using a parent/child context design.  This is incorrect.  The parent/child relationship handles this for you, automatically, whenever you save the child context.  When you listen for and consume that notification you are forcing Core Data to process that information a second time, on the main thread.
3. It is not clear what "background context" you are passing around as you do not show the code that calls your `-add...` methods.  Background contexts should not persist for long periods of time.  They are really meant to be used and destroyed.  The longer you have a background context in existence the further from the main context it is going to be as changes in the main context do **NOT** get passed down to the child contexts.

### Update

My apologies, I misread the code.  Since you are merging the changes from a background thread into the main thread, there is no way to avoid blocking the main thread.  This is one of the primary reasons for the creation of the parent/child design.

The only way to avoid this, and it is not recommended would be to:

1. Stand up a new `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` pointed at the same sqlite file
2. Update that `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` from the background thread
3. Notify the main `NSManagedObjectContext` to reload all data

This will avoid *most* of the main thread blocking but the expense in code complexity is almost always too much.

Comment: @marcus : ** You are listening for and merging changes from NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification calls when you are using a parent/child context design. This is incorrect. The parent/child relationship handles this for you, automatically, whenever you save the child context.**  
I am not using the parent -child context type ( nested contexts ). But rather using the pre- ios 5 Type of coredata merging . 

The 'background Context'is a new context being allocated every time i perform any process in the background queue. which i mentioned in the  `code` + performInBackground method `code`

Comment: @ Marcus S. Zarra: here is the code for your reference .
+ (void)performInTheBackground:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext *blockContext))bgBlock {

    dispatch_async([CGSharedCoreData backgroundSaveQueue],
    ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [newContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:CG_CORE_DATA.persistentStoreCoordinator]; // Create a managed object context
        [newContext setStalenessInterval:0.0];
        [newContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];

        bgBlock(newContext);

    });
}

Comment: @Marcus S Zarra : Thank you . Will try this out .